# TypeScript license

Tags: licensing, typescript

I have been all over the http://www.typescriptlang.org/ site and cannot find current information about the license for TypeScript.  We would like to start exploring TypeScript as a replacement for JavaScript in our organization, but are unclear on the terms of use.  The old codeplex site indicated it was licensed under Apache Version 2.0, but I can't find anything recent.  Does anyone have pointers to the latest terms?

Existing questions on the topic seem to be regarding the preview version of TypeScript.

Thanks!
Paul

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [licensing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274963/1699210)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about licensing / terms of use / legal issues, not programming or software development. See the [help/on-topic] for more.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The authorative source tells that the current version is Apache licensed as well: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/LICENSE.txt

Comment: This looks perfect.  Next time I will know to look in the source package.  I guess I was trying to avoid touching it too much until I was sure we it was safe.  Thanks for your help.